# What must be done before rebirth in the hell realms becomes inevitable?

Tags: karma, ethics, rebirth, realms

I once read a commentary by a Rinpoche talking about how the karma of killing a single fly grew at an exponential rate.

Since negative karma grows so quickly, what actions, and what amount of those actions, makes rebirth in a hell realm inevitable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Five offences in Buddhism which are said to irrevocably propel the offender into hell are:

1. patricide,
2. matricide,
3. killing an Arhat,
4. injuring a Buddha,
5. creating schism in the Sangha

Smaller offenses like common murder, adultery etc. can still be "repaired" even if with great difficulties.